# Flutter: unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null

Tags: android, api, flutter, dart

I am facing the problem during login from flutter to laravel api. I have used the below code and got error message:

```
Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null.
```

**login.cart code**

````
```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qtrack/api/api.dart';
import 'package:qtrack/Pages/Dashboard/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:qtrack/Pages/Register/register.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  LoginPageState createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
  String msgStatus = '';

  final TextEditingController _emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  initState() {
    read();
    super.initState();
  }

  read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;
    if (value != '0') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
      ));
    }
  }

  _onPressed() {
    setState(() {
      if ((_emailController.text).trim().toLowerCase().isNotEmpty &&
          ((_passwordController.text).trim().isNotEmpty)) {
        databaseHelper
            .loginData(_emailController.text.trim().toLowerCase(),
                _passwordController.text.trim())
            .whenComplete(() {
          if (databaseHelper.status) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
          } else {
            _showDialog();
            msgStatus = 'Check email or password';
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _showDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Failed'),
            content: new Text('Check your email or password'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new RaisedButton(
                child: new Text(
                  'Close',
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            ///////////  background///////////
            new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  stops: [0.0, 0.4, 0.9],
                  colors: [
                    Color(0xFFFF835F),
                    Color(0xFFFC663C),
                    Color(0xFFFF3F1A),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),

            Positioned(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Card(
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            /////////////  Email//////////////

                            TextField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                              controller: _emailController,
                              cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.account_circle,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: "Email",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              ),
                            ),

                            /////////////// password////////////////////

                            TextField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFF000000)),
                              cursorColor: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                              controller: _passwordController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              obscureText: true,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(
                                  Icons.vpn_key,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                hintText: "Password",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Color(0xFF9b9b9b),
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                              ),
                            ),
                            /////////////  LogIn Botton///////////////////
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: FlatButton(
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      top: 8, bottom: 8, left: 10, right: 10),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Login',
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 15.0,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                color: Color(0xFFFF835F),
                                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                                shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                onPressed: _onPressed,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    ////////////   new account///////////////
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              new MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => RegisterPage()));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          'Create new Account',
                          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            decoration: TextDecoration.none,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```
````

**api.dart code**
```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

````
class DatabaseHelper {
  String serverUrl = "http://localhost/qtrack-api/public/api";
  var status;
  var token;

  loginData(String email, String password) async {
    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/login";
    final response = await http.post(myUrl,
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
        body: {"email": "$email", "password": "$password"});
    status = response.body.contains('success');

    var data = json.decode(response.body);

    if (status) {
      _save(data["token"]);
    } else {
      print('data : ${data["error"]}');
    }
  }

  registerData(String name, String email, String password) async {
    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/register";
    final response = await http.post(myUrl,
        headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'},
        body: {"name": "$name", "email": "$email", "password": "$password"});
    status = response.body.contains('error');

    var data = json.decode(response.body);

    if (status) {
      print('data : ${data["error"]}');
    } else {
      print('data : ${data["token"]}');
      _save(data["token"]);
    }
  }

  Future<List> getData() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/products/";
    http.Response response = await http.get(myUrl, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    });
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }

  void deleteData(int id) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/products/$id";
    http.delete(myUrl, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    }).then((response) {
      print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body : ${response.body}');
    });
  }

  void addData(String name, String price) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "$serverUrl/products";
    http.post(myUrl, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    }, body: {
      "name": "$name",
      "price": "$price"
    }).then((response) {
      print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body : ${response.body}');
    });
  }

  void editData(int id, String name, String price) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;

    String myUrl = "http://flutterapitutorial.codeforiraq.org/api/products/$id";
    http.put(myUrl, headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $value'
    }, body: {
      "name": "$name",
      "price": "$price"
    }).then((response) {
      print('Response status : ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body : ${response.body}');
    });
  }

  _save(String token) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = token;
    prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;
    print('read : $value');
  }
}
```
````

**Dubug console log**

```
E/flutter ( 8339): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(171)] Unhandled Exception: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
E/flutter ( 8339): #0      LoginPageState._onPressed.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
package:qtrack/…/Login/login.dart:48
E/flutter ( 8339): #1      _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1182:47)
E/flutter ( 8339): #2      _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 8339): #3      _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:167:18)
E/flutter ( 8339): #4      Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:666:39)
E/flutter ( 8339): #5      Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:722:37)
E/flutter ( 8339): #6      Future._completeError  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
E/flutter ( 8339): #7      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError  (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
E/flutter ( 8339): #8      DatabaseHelper.loginData (package:qtrack/api/api.dart)
E/flutter ( 8339): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 8339): #9      LoginPageState._onPressed.<anonymous closure> 
package:qtrack/…/Login/login.dart:45
E/flutter ( 8339): #10     State.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1244
E/flutter ( 8339): #11     LoginPageState._onPressed 
package:qtrack/…/Login/login.dart:41
E/flutter ( 8339): #12     _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:993
E/flutter ( 8339): #13     _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:1111
E/flutter ( 8339): #14     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:183
E/flutter ( 8339): #15     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:598
E/flutter ( 8339): #16     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:287
E/flutter ( 8339): #17     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:222
E/flutter ( 8339): #18     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:476
E/flutter ( 8339): #19     PointerRouter._dispatch 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:77
E/flutter ( 8339): #20     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122
E/flutter ( 8339): #21     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach  (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:377:8)
E/flutter ( 8339): #22     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120
E/flutter ( 8339): #23     PointerRouter.route 
package:flutter/…/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106
E/flutter ( 8339): #24     GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:219
E/flutter ( 8339): #25     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:199
E/flutter ( 8339): #26     GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:157
E/flutter ( 8339): #27     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:103
E/flutter ( 8339): #28     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:87
E/flutter ( 8339): #29     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1206:13)
E/flutter ( 8339): #30     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
E/flutter ( 8339): #31     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:1005:7)
E/flutter ( 8339): #32     _invoke1  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:267:10)
E/flutter ( 8339): #33     _dispatchPointerDataPacket  (dart:ui/hooks.dart:176:5)
E/flutter ( 8339):
```

Waiting for response.
Thanks

Comment: Show where the error is pointing to.

Comment: Half your `async` functions are probably not what you want them to be. Both `await` and returning the Future from a `.then()` call works, but it seems you forgot to actually *return* the future you get from your `.then()` calls. That might not be your problrm, but your problem might be much easier to find if the rest of your program is correct. For starters, it might be easier to focus on *either* `await` *or* `.then()` calls until you get a better grasp of the concepts.

Comment: ```if (databaseHelper.status) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/dashboard');
          }```    In databaseHelper.status error is pointing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing value = 0 but checking value = '0'

```
  read() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'token';
    final value = prefs.get(key) ?? 0;
    if (value != '0') {
      Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(),
      ));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Must assign to the DatabaseHelper Status his Bool value

Change

```
if (databaseHelper.status)
```

to

```
if (databaseHelper.status == true)
```